# publish range data from android app

Tags: android-core, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to publish range data (Fake) from Android application to the PC.

- I have successfully written a rosjava package rosjava_range which is nothing but a publisher and subscriber of the message type "sensor_msgs.Range._TYPE".
- As per instruction I created my new application by copying android_tutorial_pubsub.
- I tried to modify the build.gradle file to add my own package (class)

dependencies {

compile 'ros.rosjava_core:rosjava_tutorial_pubsub:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
compile 'ros.rosjava_core:rosjava_range:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

}

- And then made changes in the MainActivity.java file to import the following class.

import org.ros.rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.Talker;

import org.ros.rosjava_range.Range_Talker;

I was not able to build successfully. I get the following error:

-post-package:

-do-debug:
[echo] Library project: do not create apk...
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/suraj/my_workspace/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/suraj/my_workspace/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/suraj/my_workspace/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/suraj/my_workspace/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/bin/build.prop

-post-build:

debug:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
:android_tutorial_range:deployLibs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':android_tutorial_range:compile'.

> Could not find group:org.ros.rosjava_range, module:rosjava_range, version:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
> Required by:
> ros.android_core:android_tutorial_range:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.453 secs

What am I missing here? Do I have to add the path to my rosjava_range package?

Thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38824/publish-range-data-from-android-app/) by [ss_robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/348/ss_robotics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2012-07-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution was very simple. Instead of linking it from another package you have to add those files in the src folder and make sure that you import it ( import org.ros.rosjava_range.Range_Talker; ) in the MainActivity.java file.

---

Originally posted by [ss_robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/348/ss_robotics/) with karma: 75 on 2012-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0